# What is the difference between UNNotificationServiceExtension and UNNotificationContentExtension

Tags: ios

What is the difference between UNNotificationServiceExtension and UNNotificationContentExtension.

What can one do and the other cannot. I've got through doc but couldn't figure out exact differences

Comment: Basic difference, UNNotificationServiceExtension is for processing of data(downloading media, storing data, calling any service) received through notification and UNNotificationContentExtension can be used for displaying data in Notification custom UI. Both supports iOS 12 and above.

Answer (score 2):

First of all they are different objects:

- **[UNNotificationServiceExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension)** - is an class. It's *"lets you
  customize the content of a remote notification before it is delivered
  to the user"*. *For example, you could use the extension to decrypt
  an encrypted data block or to download images associated with the
  notification.*
  So you don't change the UI of Notification, but you
  can modify notification content.
- **[UNNotificationContentExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/unnotificationcontentextension)** - is an protocol. *"You adopt this
  protocol in the custom UIViewController subclass that you use to
  present your interface."*
  So you can create custom interface for
  your notification (ex. for some type of notification) and add your
  controls.

Answer (score 0):

`UNNotificationServiceExtension`:

- It has no user interface, so less control over this. Just limited functionality
- It has excellent background mode. First, it prepares himself then displays the user.

`UNNotificationContentExtension`:

- It has a user interface, You can customize your desired.
- Its instantly displays. and content download starts after displaying.